# React-Virtualized: Forcing row style repaint instead of styleCache

Tags: react-virtualized

In a Table, I have rows that have different heights depending on the data. For example:

[image]

Everything works fine, until I sort out the columns and the cached row heights outputs an undesirable result.

[image]

I discovered it's the `top` css property which causes the result

[image]

It is reset by a cache, which I think is happening [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/source/Grid/defaultCellRangeRenderer.js#L57-L87).

But I still can't figure out how to fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `top` property is how react-virtualized positions windowed rows. (You might want to step through a couple of [these slides](https://bvaughn.github.io/forward-js-2017/#/12/1) for an overview of how the library works.)

You're right that the issue is ultimately a caching one though. If the data for your list/table/grid changes, you'll need to let react-virtualized know that its cached sizes may be invalid. Assuming you have a `ref` handle on your `Table` then you can just call [`recomputeRowHeights`](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/Table.md#recomputerowheights-index-number) like so:

```
// Passing 0 (or no index) means to recompute all rows
tableRef.recomputeRowHeights(0);
```

Are you using `CellMeasurer` to measure your `Table` rows? If so, you'll want to make sure you're passing an `keyMapper` that knows how to identify your rows by *id* rather than *index*. (This way you won't need to re-measure every row after a sort operation.) For example:

```
const keyMapper = (rowIndex, columnIndex) => {
  const data = yourArray[rowIndex]; // Assuming your data is in an Array
  return `${data.id}:${columnIndex}`; // Assuming your data has an 'id' attribute
}
```

It's built with `List` rather than `Table` but you can see an example of `CellMeasurer` being used in this [mock Twitter app](https://tweets.now.sh/) (source code [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/tweets/blob/master/src/components/TweetList.js)).

Comment: The links were very helpful. I had misunderstood the method. Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean 'you'll want to make sure passing an `keyMapper` to `CellMeasurerCache`? I don't see a propType `keyMapper` for `CellMeasurer` in your docs (only see it for `CellMeasurerCache`?

Comment: Also, in your example of a keyMapper, wouldn't columnIndex not suffice for a keyMap because it is not unique?

Comment: Previously I was using only the index as a key. Your data.id attributes saved my day. Bundle of thanks